# Why is overwriting $GLOBALS killing the_content()?

Tags: filters, the-content, globals

I'm in the `single.php` and now need to use `the_content()` instead of just `$post->post_content`; for youtube embeds etc.–

in other projects `the_content()` and `apply_filters("the_content", ...)` does what it should do, but not in this `single.php` ... Twentyseventeen theme with the same plugins works great with `the_content()`; so it must be my theme.

After hours of researching and fiddling around I found out that I did this pretty early in the code:

```
$GLOBALS = array(
    "active_menu" => "...",
    "something_else" => true
);

// don't ask me why I did this, I was a even more a noob back then; 
// it's been working fine so far; no time to refactor.. u know the excuses–

// of course I just do it like this now:
$GLOBALS["active_menu"] = "...";
$GLOBALS["something_else"] = true;
```

When I wanted to see what might be so crucial in the "original" `$GLOBALS`, the browser loaded like it went to Oblivion and back again. So much stuff inside this var.

So here's the question

1. Why did an overwritten `$GLOBALS` which is sooo big, kill the filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Template tags like `the_content()` and `the_title()` are dependent on the global `$post` variable (`$GLOBALS['post']`).

See the source code for `get_post()`, which `get_the_title()`, for example, uses to get the current post so it can get its title:

```
function get_post( $post = null, $output = OBJECT, $filter = 'raw' ) {
    if ( empty( $post ) && isset( $GLOBALS['post'] ) )
        $post = $GLOBALS['post'];
```

WordPress is heavily dependent on global variables. See [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Global_Variables) codex article on the global variables. You *really* shouldn't be overwriting it entirely or you'll break more than just template tags. I'm surprised you made it this far, honestly.

Comment: That's what surprised me the most by that revelation aswell! That's why I am asking this question :D – Thanks for the article and the nice answer :)